# bash: pipe-character in variable for command-substitution

Tags: linux, bash

Can please someone explain, why this is not working??

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="ps aux | grep -v grep"
cnt=$($cmd)
```

I get an error from ps.

```
error: garbage option

Usage:
  ps [options]
.....
```

"ps aux" only will be ok - but not with any additional piped commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better and safer to use function to store a pipeline command as:

unset cmd cnt

```
cmd() {
   ps aux | grep -v grep
}
```

and use it in command substitution as:

```
cnt="$(cmd)"
```

[See BASH FAQ on storing command line in a variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "better and safer"?

Comment: You need `unset -f cmd` to unset the function. Not that you need to, since you can just redefine it.

Answer (score 1):

To execute the content of your variable `$cmd` you have to use `eval`:

`cnt=$(eval $cmd)`

Comment: Yes, seems so. That is not the case if there is no pipe. Interesting....

Answer (score -1):

Please use this command:-

cmd= `ps aux | grep -v grep`

when we want to use o/p from other command we need to use actute (`) instead of double quotes (")

Thanks

Comment: But they didn't want the output of the command to `cmd`, just the command itself. There's the command substitution actually running it on the following line.